# Passing variables to .css to set top and left position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know there are other questions regarding this but none of the solutions seem to work for me.  I am unable to get my "top" and "left" positions to read the variables (YOff, XOff) defined above.  It always defaults to 0,0.  Any help would be appreciated.  For what it's worth, I know the variables are calculating correctly because I alerted them to verify.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.marker').mouseover(function(e){
        var location = $(this).attr("id");
        var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
        var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

        var XOff = Math.round( (e.pageX - offset_l) );
        var YOff = Math.round( (e.pageY - offset_t) );

        $('.city').hide();
        $("#" + location + "-market")
        .show()
        .css({
            top: YOff, 
            left: XOff
        });

    });                
    $('.city').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.city').hide();
    }); 
});
```

A little detail on what I'm trying to do... On a map (bg image) when you mouseover a city (.marker) that has an absolute position I have a div (# + location + -market) show that contains some info on that city.  I'd like to get that div to position close to the city.

Comment: Just a quick idea = do you need to do  `{"top":YOff,"left":XOff}`? - Putting the top and left attributes in quotes?

Comment: Watch for "Tyrannical Tyrannosaurus" suggestion. Share a fiddle link if still not resolved.

Comment: css properties with a hyphen need to be quoted . I guess top would work even without a quote

Comment: YOff should be YOff + "px" and XOff should be XOff + "px" try this instead

Comment: should be `.css({"top":YOff+ "px","left":XOff+ "px"});`

Comment: So far no luck but thanks for all the suggestions.  I'll work on getting this into a fiddle.  Sorry, should've done that prior to posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [-This Link-](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) I changed your `.css()` function into this:

```
$("#" + location + "-market").show().offset({
    top: YOff, left: XOff
});
```

Which made your jquery file look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.marker').mouseover(function (e) {
        var location = $(this).attr("id");
        var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
        var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();

        var XOff = Math.round((e.pageX - offset_l));
        var YOff = Math.round((e.pageY - offset_t));

        $('.city').hide();
        $("#" + location + "-market").show().offset({
            top: YOff, left: XOff
        });
    });

    $('.city').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.city').hide();
    });
});
```

Fiddle [-Here-](http://jsfiddle.net/PKe8Y/13/). Hopefully this produces the results you wanted!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#selector").css({"top":YOff+ "px","left":XOff+ "px","position": "absolute" });
```

see in action with modified fiddle:-
http://jsfiddle.net/md4cD/

Comment: use this $("#selector").css({"top":YOff+ "px","left":XOff+ "px","position": "absolute" });

Comment: for some reason it isn't working in my original file.  must be something wrong in my css but I see it works in the fiddle.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: UPDATE: This did work in my file.  I didn't realize you changed the variables as well.  Again, many thanks!